# Filtering an Android Broadcast receiver by action and extra

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am able to filter the broadcasts in my Android application by action. Eg:

```
 <receiver android:name=".receiver.TasksModifiedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>>
            <action android:name="myapp.TASKS_MODIFIED_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

However, can I further filter them by "extras" that are supplied in the intent?

Eg, application A sends a broadcast:

```
Intent taskBroadcastIntent = new Intent();
taskBroadcastIntent.setAction(ApplicationConstants.TASKS_MODIFIED_BROADCAST_ACTION);
taskBroadcastIntent.putExtra("TaskType", taskType);
taskBroadcastIntent.putExtra("UserName", CommonCache.getCommonCache().getValue(CommonCache.USER_NAME));
taskBroadcastIntent.putExtra("Environment", Constants.ENVIRONMENT);
context.sendBroadcast(taskBroadcastIntent);
```

Now, application B should only receive the broadcast if "TaskType" extra is set  to "task1",
and application C should only receive the broadcast if "TaskType" extra is set  to "task2".

Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.
I cannot find this ability in the Android developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible. But here is what I will do,

Create a common receiver, You will be receiving the app context and intent. So get the taskType using getStringExtra("TaskType") and based on that trigger the respective broadcast intent.

Comment: Thanks, we are already programmatically checking for 'TaskType' in our receivers and only processing if it matches the one we want. Was hoping to avoid this programmatic check